# Swift: Adding gradient layer to button. Layer length error

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, gradient

```
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
let colorTop = UIColor(red: 112.0/255.0, green: 219.0/255.0, blue: 155.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 86.0/255.0, green: 197.0/255.0, blue: 238.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

gradient.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
gradient.frame = loginButton.bounds
gradient.cornerRadius = 5
loginButton.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

[image: Gradient too long]

The resulting gradient runs off goes beyond the button's frame. Why does this happen?

Comment: Maybe try setting the `bounds` property of the gradient layer to be equal to that of the loginButton's layer?

Answer (score 9):

Probably you are setting gradient layer in viewDidLoad() or viewWillAppear(). At that time controller did not calculated views sizes. At time you add this sublayer button size was not calculated yet, so sublayer size is wrong. So you should fix next things:

1. First of all you should add gradient at viewDidAppear(), at this point all view's sizes are calculated.
2. Second, you should use layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex:index) instead of addSublayer(layer). Because in your case sublayer will hide buttons native layer (title, background...)
3. You should recalculate your sublayer size in viewDidLayoutSubviews(). Because when your button will change it's size (while rotating for example), sublayer will not change it's frame, so you should change it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you! Putting my code in viewWillAppear works solves the problem.

Comment: Do you mind answering a quick follow-up question? After putting the code in viewdidload, segues to this view controller look bad, because the animated vc doesn't have the gradient attached. How do I get around this?

Comment: Sorry, for late response, was very busy. You can do next things: 1. Subclass uibutton, set there CAGradientLayer property, add this layer in init method and override layoutSubviews() method, where you should recalculate CAGradientLayer's frame like: gradientLayer.frame = button.bounds; 2. You can create this layer property in controller, add it to button in viewDidLoad, and recalculate layer's frame in viewDidLayoutSubview. I would use first method.

Answer (score 5):

Add clipsToBounds and cornerRadius to loginbutton. That should fix the problem.

```
loginButton.clipsToBounds = true
loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

Comment: Great answer. I was using a custom button so I can adjust the border color, radius and all that from the Launch screen and upon creating a gradient background, the color was spilling out beyond the border. Adding clipsToBounds = true to my custom button solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is your Login Button's frame correct?It seems correct when I reproduce

```
        let loginButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 300, height: 30))
        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)

        let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        let colorTop = UIColor(red: 112.0/255.0, green: 219.0/255.0, blue: 155.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 86.0/255.0, green: 197.0/255.0, blue: 238.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

        gradient.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.frame = loginButton.bounds
        gradient.cornerRadius = 5

        loginButton.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

And it appear like below

[image]